# In Microsoft SQL is there an existing stored procedure to list all tables of a schema?

Tags: sql-server

**Background**: I need to truncate all tables in a schema.

As a first step, I am looking for an existing (system) stored procedure in Microsoft SQL that lists all tables in a schema.

This query gives me the results I am looking for

```
SELECT NAME AS TABLE_NAME
FROM SYS.TABLES
WHERE SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID) = 'myschema' -- PUT YOUR SCHEMA NAME HERE
ORDER BY NAME;
```

But is there an stored procedure provided by Microsoft to do this?

Comment: Why, specifically, would there be (a desire for) a stored procedure when that view is right there? What benefit/use case do you think a stored procedure adds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [sp_tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) system stored procedure can be used to list tables and views, filtering as desired. Example for your use case:

```
EXEC sp_tables @table_owner = 'myschema', @table_type = "'TABLE'";
```

Note the double quotes surrounding the @table_type parameter are needed and detailed in the documentation.

Personally, I would use the catalog views like the query in your question.